# Unable to renew iOS developer university program

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I get this error when I try to register with the "developer program ios". I'll have to re-create apple id?
[image: error]

Comment: "Please contact Apple Developer Support"?

Comment: It's an University Program. Are you doing this on behalf of some university? Or you are a student who joined the team of his university?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/university.html

[image]

If you're authorized to renew the program on behalf your University, it sounds like you're going to have to contact Apple support directly in order to renew your program.